# Sed - Adding white spaces to the end of line

Tags: sed, whitespace

after some research here i ran across this use of SED :

```
sed 's/$/       /' filein > fileout
```

This worked as expected in some files, and added the spaces to the end of the line.

My problem is that in a different file like this :

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
```

and after running that same command to append some spaces (7) at the end of each line, it basicly adds a different line and puts the 7 spaces there, like :

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB(CR)
spacesx7(cr)(lf)
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC(CR)
spacesx7(cr)(lf)
```

Could someone help me? Thank you in advance

Comment: What OS are you on? What version of `sed`? If your line separator is cr-lf, this is significant.

Comment: The line separator is CR/LF but it was the same in the previous file where this command worked. Should i somehow remove the line separator or look for another solution? Maybe with awk?

Comment: Is this Cygwin on Windows or anything like that?

Comment: just run dos2unix or similar on the file first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
dos2unix < filein | sed 's/$/       /' > fileout
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I just needed to do a unix2dos in the end to bring back the CR before every LF, because that's how they requested the end format.